# click related keyword like a search input

Tags: android, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

Hi sorry for my bad title (i really dont know how to phrase it better) but i have a cardview just like this [cardview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHJ2G.png) where the result/s returned are based on the user has input on the search bar.

All of the information returned are based on my database (DB Browser for SQLite). the cardview itself is not clickable but now I want the related keyword section to be clickable in a way where if a user click on one of the related keywords, it will open the cardview of that keyword like the same way when if the user search on it. (pardon me for my bad english!) As of now I only know that I have to add the clickable=true on the UI. However, logic-wise, I am not sure.

Below are my codes:

**Cardview UI**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardElevation="5dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/keyword"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Baggage Management Interface Device (BMID) Testing 
        123"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/acronym"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#a8000000"
        android:text="GST"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:textColor="#a8000000"
        android:text="If none are set then 'GST' is set to NULL"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/relatedKeyword"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:textColor="#a8000000"
        android:text="Related Keyword:"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/relatedKeyword1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#a8000000"
            android:text="Keyword 1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/relatedKeyword2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#a8000000"
            android:text="Keyword 2"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/relatedKeyword3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#a8000000"
            android:text="Keyword 3"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Search Adapter + SearchView Holder**

```
package com.example.run_h.boav2.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.run_h.boav2.Model.Knowledge;
import com.example.run_h.boav2.R;

import java.util.List;

class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

public TextView keyword, description, acronym, relatedkeyword1, 
relatedkeyword2, relatedkeyword3;

public SearchViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    keyword = itemView.findViewById(R.id.keyword);
    acronym = itemView.findViewById(R.id.acronym);
    description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    relatedkeyword1= itemView.findViewById(R.id.relatedKeyword1);
    relatedkeyword2= itemView.findViewById(R.id.relatedKeyword2);
    relatedkeyword3= itemView.findViewById(R.id.relatedKeyword3);

}
```

}

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder> 
{

private Context context;
private List<Knowledge> knowledge;

public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<Knowledge> knowledge) {
    this.context = context;
    this.knowledge = knowledge;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent,     
false);
    return new SearchViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder holder, int position)     
{

    holder.keyword.setText(knowledge.get(position).getKeyword());
    holder.description.setText(knowledge.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.acronym.setText(knowledge.get(position).getAcronym());
    holder.relatedkeyword1.setText(knowledge.get(position).getRelatedkeyword1());
    holder.relatedkeyword2.setText(knowledge.get(position).getRelatedkeyword2());
    holder.relatedkeyword3.setText(knowledge.get(position).getRelatedkeyword3());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return knowledge.size();
}
```

}

Anyone knows how I can implement this? Much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please remove unnecessary codes.

Comment: @tahsinRupam What unnecessary codes, ya? Where do I add them?

Comment: _it will open the cardview of that keyword like the same way when if the user search on it._ What does it mean actually? Please elaborate.

Comment: @tahsinRupam E.g my screen shot, I searched for "first" and as such the result  ("First Bag" appeared. As you can see, there are 3 related keywords ("BMID", "GMID", "LBT"). I want those 3 related keywords to be clickable where when the user click on it, it will open the cardview of that same keyword the user clicked on.

Comment: Why don't you set `onClickListener`s to the related keyword `textView`s?

Comment: @tahsinRupam I might be able to do that but is there a better solution? It is because I have 100+ rows of data and each of their "Related Keywords" are all different. Does that mean I have to create a separate 100+ cardview and ID for each Keyword just so I can make them clickable?

Comment: Not really. You have to count how many keywords you are getting from the database & create `textView` programatically through a loop. And use single `cardView`. Just pass the keyword name & other necessary texts.

Comment: @tahsinRupam I have 100 rows of data and they are all associated to one another. Each cardview has 3 related keywords. I think I get the single cardView thing and pass the necessary texts part. But what about the "create textView programmatically through a loop"? Perhaps could you guide me or do you know of any guides/links I could refer to?

Comment: If you have keywords of fixed number (as 3) then you don't need to create `textView`s programatically. Hope you got the workaround.

Comment: @tahsinRupam I guess so.. But how I reference the second cardView back to the first (searched keyword & returned result) cardView? And also, does that mean I have to create a new Activity, since I need a destination class when I implement a onClickListener?

Comment: Where do you actually want to show the second cardView, (Through a dialog or open another activity) is all up-to you.

Comment: @tahsinRupam Thank you for your advices so far!! I will try again and again!